# What is the ship shown just before the Enterprise in the ST: Enterprise opening credits?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

In *Star Trek: Enterprise*, season 1 at least, the opening credits show a bunch of aircraft and spacecraft.  Just before the *Enterprise* shows up, there is another ship of similar configuration.

[image]

Is there any information on that ship and what it could do?  It is shown after the *Phoenix*, and since the progression seems to show craft from more primitive to more advanced once would presume that it is a precursor to the *Enterprise* itself.

Comment: I would agree with your guess, but I'm not certain. I'm don't think any other info (including a name) is provided about it in canon. There might be a non-canon reference somewhere, but most likely it's just to show something developmentally between the Pheonix and the Enterprise.

Comment: It's the S.S. Emmette

Comment: @Valorum: agreed, and yes this appears to be a duplicate.  Should I remove the question?

Comment: No, we leave dupes up as signposts for future searches (AKA googlebait)